# How to Search custom columns for a content type and display in SPGridView

Tags: search, content-type, fulltextsqlquery

I have a custom task content type based on the task content type which has a custom priority column, custom assigned to column etc. There are many instances of the task list in multiple site collections.

My requirement is to present a view (custom web part) to a logged in user of all the tasks which are assigned to them. This view needs to look like the actual task list view but filtered for that user.

I have been advised to use search to solve the problem, but my search knowledge is limited.
Currently, I have been looking at the FullTextSQLQuery but I'm unsure on how to get all the columns in the content type. I want to get the results as a datatable with all the columns from the task list and bind them to a SPGridView.

I want to say for example:
query = "SELECT Priority, taskUrl, Status, workflowUrl, ItemId, ListUrl from Scopes() WHERE scope = 'My Custom Tasks Scope' and assignedUser = " + SPContext.Current.User.LoginName;

Any ideas on how I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty big question so I'll do my best to outline the steps you'll need to take in order to get this done.

First, you'll want to **make sure all of your columns are crawled**. If you're using out of the box Tasks lists then some of them may already be in there. If not, it will take some [monkeying around in Central Admin](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/05/21/enterprise-search-sql-and-sharepoint/) (full disclosure: link to my blog). I'd recommend setting up a small test console app to query the index so you can see which results come back.. it is worth the effort because you'll need it later.

Second, setup a **very basic SPGridView** with some *dummy data*. Erik Burger has [an excellent series about building an SPGridView](http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/). I'm not kidding about the dummy data either. SPGridView's are a tough beast if you haven't messed with them before.. plus you'll have some time while full crawls are running in your DEV environment.

Third and lastly, **combine** the various queries and `FullTextSQLQuery` code you've written with your basic SPGridView. Hopefully by now, you [have some code that returns a DataTable](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx) which will be easy to hook up to the `ObjectDataSource` in your SPGridView.