# SPGridView problems

Tags: web-part, spgridview

Can someone tell me how to use SPGridView please, I want to know how it works. Do I need to create a data table first then add it to table or create table first then add table to SPGridView.

I need it in a webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table you want to bind SPGridView control with is SQL table then you can simply bind SPGridView with your SQL table, I would explain it in details but its already explained properly in this similar type of question,

[Sharepoint SPGridView Data Reneder-SQL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/sharepoint-spgridview-data-reneder-sql)